# ActiveRecord attribute sum of users, votes query rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to show in my view all the attributes related to "rateable_id: 3" for example.
I am new to querying dbs and showing results in view. Also I want to display in view the sum of "rater_id:"( how many users have voted) for "rateable_id: 3" for example.

This is in my ranking_controller.rb:

```
class RankingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @rankings = Rate.find(:all)
  end
end
```

This is in my table rates:

```
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 11
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:23.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:23.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 12
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:24.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:24.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 13
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:25.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:25.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 14
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: execution
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:26.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:26.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 15
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:27.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:27.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 16
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:30.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:30.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 17
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 18
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 19
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:32.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:32.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 25
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:46.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:46.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 26
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:49.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:49.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 27
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:51.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:51.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 28
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: execution
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:53.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:53.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 29
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:54.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:54.000000000 Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely want to do this in the `show` method in your controller, as that will call a specific `Ranking`:

```
class RankingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @rankings = Rate.find(:all)
  end

  def show
    @ranking = Rate.where(:rateable_id => params[:id])
  end
end
```

Then, in your `show` view, you could use `count` to get the total number of `Rate` records returned against unique `rater_id` values:

`@ranking.map(&:rater_id).uniq.count`

Answer (score 1):

### For the sums:

You can use two queries

```
@rankings_by_raters = Rate.group(:rater_id).count
@rankings_by_rateable = Rate.group(:rateable_id).count
```

which will give you two hashes with the `rater` and `rateable`' s ids as keys and the relevant counts as values.

### For the show:

```
@rankings_for_rate = Rate.where(rater_id: params[:rater_id])
```